# Routing for action on default controller in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-routing

I have a default routing so if I go to www.domain.com/app/ it's, for example, the HomeController. I have another action on the control, e.g. helloworld but if I go to www.domain.com/app/helloworld it fails with a 404 (expecting helloworld controller no doubt).

How can I can non-default actions on my default controller OR how can I map the url /app/helloworld to the helloworld action. My routing looks like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
"Default", // Route name
"{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);

routes.MapRoute( //this fails with same 404 like it does when it's ommitted
"Hello", // Route name
"app/helloworld", // URL with parameters
new { controller = "Home", action = "HellowWorld", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Basically I need:

/app/ => Controller = Home, Action = Index

/app/helloworld => Controller = Home, Action = HelloWorld, 
not Controller = HelloWorld, Action - Index

/app/other => Controller = Other, Action = Index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the 2 `routes` in your Global file with this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "App/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Then verify your `HomeController` contains:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public ActionResult HelloWorld()
{
    return View();
}
```

What this is doing is that `yoursite.com/app/ANYCONTROLLER/ANYACTION` will route to the controller and action (as long as they exist,) and the default `new { controller = "Home", action = "Index"` means that if someone goes to `yoursite.com/app/` it will automatically route to `yoursite.com/app/Home/Index`.

If this doesn't work try removing the `app/` so it will look like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

What you had looks like you were trying to route `yoursite.com/Home/Index` and the second route was phrased wrong, I'm not sure what it would do but instead of `"app/helloworld` it should have looked like `"app/HelloWorld/{action}/{id}"` then `new { controller = "Home", action = "HellowWorld"` would work. So that if someone went to `yoursite.com/app` it would automatically display `yoursite.com/app/Home/HelloWorld`. Hope that helps clear some things up.

**This is the answer you want**

For some reason you don't want to create a new controller for the hello world section, your `RegisterRoutes` in the `Global` file should look like this:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Hello World", // Route name
            "App/HellowWorld/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "HelloWorld", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "App/{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
            );
    }
```

Although I would not recommend going about it this way.

Comment: Sorry these aren't working. I have clarified my routing needs above. Thx

Comment: @DaveO see my update, and try `yoursite.com/app/home/helloworld`

Comment: @DaveO I assume it worked; I'm curious to know why you didn't want to create a separate `HelloWorld Controller`, or did you end up going that route?

Comment: I used your last answer. I didn't want another controller as this particular app only has one and it's a simple response to a form submission. Anyway, it worked brilliantly thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should just need one route for this.  Instead of hard-coding the action, make it a variable, but include the default:

```
routes.MapRoute( //this fails with same 404 like it does when it's ommitted
    "Hello", // Route name
    "app/{action}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "HelloWorld", id = UrlParameter.Optional } 
);
```

This way, when you go to **www.domain.com/app/**, it will get the default action (HelloWorld).  But you can still specify actions in the route as **www.domain.com/app/someotheraction**.

Also, keep in mind that the first matching route is selected... so you should consider moving the default route to the end, or leaving it out completely.  In the example **www.domain.com/app/helloworld**, it matches the default route with *app* as the controller and *helloworld* as the action (which of course is invalid, hence the 404).

Comment: Thanks. You mean I don't need the two MapRoute calls? I tried just the above and it fails with a white screen. Changing my second call to this still gives me a 404.

Comment: @DaveO right-- I'd normally move the first route to the end of the list, that way it functions as a "fallback", without preempting your core routes.